# React, how can I submit updates to Input box when clicking outside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking for a solution in which a user can enter text into an input, and when they click anywhere outside of the component, it submits, saves the value.

In my case I have a top level component which dynamically generates Text Input components.It passes in the properties including an UpdateValue function.

In these functional components I am using the ability to add an event listener to the document, and then I detect if the click comes from outside the component in question. Having done a lot of research on stackoverflow, this seems to be the agreed upon method.

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClick);
    return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown',handleClick);
    }
},[])

const handleClick = (e) => {
if(node.current.contains(e.target))
  {
      return;
  }
  updateValue()
}
```

I have this working, in that the function gets called when I click outside the component, however, the function invoked on the parent component no longer seems to have access to the state..they appear all empty. I can only guess that because we are using a generic javascript function initially, the call doesn't have access to react stack.

So, my question is, how can I make this work where I want a nested functional component that has an input, and when a user clicks off component, it runs the updateValue function which can then use some internal state data to properly update this in the DB.

FYI, I have a onchange() on the input, which updates the value in the parent component already.
So, UpdateValue() is a trigger to basically submit final changes to DB.

Answer (score 0):

Your `updateValue` should be a callback that you create inside your functional component. That should take dependencies on the state that you define there. Use `React.useCallback`